# ValueError: 'box_aspect' and 'fig_aspect' must be positive

Tags: python, geojson

I'm trying to load and display my area of interest from a GEOJSON file .
My code is bellow

```
country = gpd.read_file(os.path.join('C:/area.geojson'))
country_shape = country.geometry.values[-1]
country.plot()
plt.axis('off');
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: 'box_aspect' and 'fig_aspect' must be positive
```

Any help please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090300/graphing-points-on-a-map-but-the-error-code-is-valueerror-box-aspect-and-fi). Try:

`country.plot(aspect=1)`